# Google Map responsiveness issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am displaying a Google Map on my website, but whenever I change the window size or even when I rotate my map on a mobile device, the map is not resizing at all. I have tried everything and I still don't know what is the problem. This is what I have done:

```js
var initMap = function () {    

       var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            center: { lat: 40.7128, lng: 74.0059 },
            zoom: 10
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        
        //Not Working
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

        //Not Working
        $(window).resize(function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
        
        //Not Working
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            map.setCenter(center);
        });
        
        //Not Working
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in a DIV and resize it from there?
or would it just overwrite its size over the DIV's size?